# count how many people view my album in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to count how many people viewed my Album on Facebook?

I just see this API:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=applications,albums
```

Can i use the Graph API?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too bad it's not possible: [the graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/album) does not allow certain functionality, using the link you will find a list of all details you can view of any of your albums.

Comment: is there any way to count number of viewer of image or album ?? plz tell me as soon as possible... thanx..

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't any way to do this using Facebook, other online services (like Flickr and Google+) do support this kind of statistics.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see how many people viewed your album. That's not possible via the Graph API. You can only access the `fields` and `connections` stated here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/album/

Comment: is there any way to count number of viewer of image or album ?? plz tell me as soon as possible... thanx..